# use of undefined type in forward declaration

Tags: c++, forward-declaration

I have the following:

```
class A; // forward declaration of class A
void A::foo(int, int); // forward declaration of member function foo of A

class Functor
{
public:
    Functor(const A* in_a):m_a(in_a){}
    virtual ~Functor(){m_a= 0;};

    virtual void Do(int,int) = 0;

protected:
    const A* m_a;
};

class FunctorDerived: public Functor
{
    FunctorDerived(const A* in_a):Functor(in_a){}

    void Do(int in_source, int in_target)
    {
        m_a->foo(in_source, in_target);
    }
};


class A
{
    ....
    void foo(int, int);
    ....
}
```

When compiling compiler tells me:

```
error C2027: use of undefined type 'A'
see declaration of 'A'
```

It seems that A is not recognized by the compiler though I forward declared it and also forward declared the member function I need to use (A::foo).

I want to clarify that everything is written in a single file.

Can you please help me to understand what I did wrong?

Answer (score 1):

Move you definition of `A` on top. Then if you need implement `foo`:

```
class A
{
    void foo(int, int);
}

class Functor
{
public:
    Functor(const A* in_a):m_a(in_a){}
    virtual ~Functor(){m_a= 0;};

    virtual void Do(int,int) = 0;

protected:
    const A* m_a;
};

class FunctorDerived: public Functor
{
    FunctorDerived(const A* in_a):Functor(in_a){}

    void Do(int in_source, int in_target)
    {
        m_a->foo(in_source, in_target);
    }
};

void A::foo(int x, int y)
{
    //do smth
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`m_a->` - you're dereferencing an `A*`. At this point the compiler needs the full definition of `A`.

In short: forward declaration won't work. Provide the complete type.

Comment: no it does not. This is just regular C, you can call a function by providing only forward declaration... this is enough for the compiler, the definition is needed at link time

Comment: no, it's C++, it's a member function.

Comment: yes lol I know I am writing c++...I have just understood what you told, I thought you told to provide the function definition, and in fact you told providing the full class definition. So what I have learnt to day is that there is no way of forward declaring a member function!

Comment: yes. I guess the problem is you can't generate the code because you don't know enough details, e.g. whether the method is `virtual`. if we are lucky, the gurus here will give more details ;)